# Flutter: Select Time and Date from one button

Tags: date, button, time, flutter, dart

I have two separate buttons, one to select a date and one to select a time. How am I able to select both the date and then time by only having a single button?

For example, one the click of a "Schedule" button, a Datepicker will popup. Once the user selects a date and clicks "OK" in the Datepicker, the Timepicker will be called or popup.

**This is the code for my time and date button widgets:**

```
  DateTime _date = new DateTime.now();
  TimeOfDay _time = new TimeOfDay.now();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: new DateTime(2019),
      lastDate: new DateTime(2021),
    );

    if(picked != null && picked != _date) {
      print('Date selected: ${_date.toString()}');
      setState((){
        _date = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _time,
    );

    if(picked != null && picked != _time) {
      print('Time selected: ${_time.toString()}');
      setState((){
        _time = picked;
      });
    }
  }
```

**Widgets:**

```
    final buttonRow =  new Wrap(children: <Widget>[
        new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text('Select Date'),
          onPressed: (){_selectDate(context);}
          ),
        new RaisedButton(
          child: new Text('Select Time'),
          onPressed: (){_selectTime(context);}
          )
        ]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RaisedButton(
  child: new Text('Select Date and Time'),
  onPressed: (){ _selectDateAndTime(context); }
)

/* ... */

Future<Null> _selectDateAndTime(BuildContext context) async {
  await _selectDate(context);
  await _selectTime(context);
}
```